# If an Oblex devours a wizard's memories, can it cast the spells the wizard had prepared?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, spellcasting

Imagine that an *Elder Oblex* (from *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*. p. 219) ate a memory of a wizard.

Could it cast spells which were prepared by this wizard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The stat block for the [Elder Oblex](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/elder-oblex) (MToF, p. 219) already states what happens when it uses its *Eat Memories* ability:

> When an oblex causes a target to become memory drained, **the oblex learns all the languages the target knows and gains all its proficiencies, except any saving throw proficiencies.**

It *doesn't* state that it learns the spells known or prepared by a caster, so it doesn't.

Comment: But aren't prepared spells already includes in _memory_?

Comment: @Ohar *Eat Memory* isn't some all-powerful, knowledge-absorbing ability. It **"eats"** the memories, not absorbs them and learns every single thing the character knows. As I stated, the stat block tells you exactly what the ability does, learning spells isn't one of them.

Comment: Even if you assume it learns the words and gestures required to cast a spell, the Elder Oblex has no spell slots it can use to cast them. It's spellcasting ability is innate and doesn't grant it any.

Comment: @AllanMills No, wizard's abilities are totally not innate, not like a sorcerer's ones. Wizards just teached it from books. So it is all about memory.

Comment: @ohar you're technically right. But mechanically speaking, it is innate (as in, built into the class and not granted by outside, generic rules and mechanic). The distinction betweeen the flavour (eats memory) and the mechanic (gains its proficiencies and saving throws. Nothing else) is an important one.

Comment: Purple mknkey's answer comes from a pure mechanical stand point. Any gm is free to add details and new mechanic, but answers on this site usually deal with RAW as de default